# SetContentView results in a blank UI when called from elsewhere in the application

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to abstract the base UI of an application such that it can be extended by child fragments, inheriting the main elements such as the elements of the navigation and settings menus. The children would then take the basic UI and create the rest of the UI, however currently unless you explicitly set the view within the child class' onCreate method, the result is a blank activity.

Is it simply not possible to set the content view anywhere other than within the oncreate of the child class?

Code below:

Abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BaseUIActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

protected DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //generateUI(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, m);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {...}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {...}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {...}

public void generateUI(int layoutID){


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Log.d("layoutID: ",""+String.valueOf(layoutID));
    this.setContentView(layoutID);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    Log.d("Drawer: ", "" + String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)));
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    Log.d("Toggle: ", "" + String.valueOf(toggle));
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}
```

}

Sample Child:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseUIActivity implements OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //generateUI(R.layout.activity_main);

    //listViewEvents = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewEvents);

}
```

}

Comment: Your baseclass is abstract, you need to pass your view to generate the View for the First Activity.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Unless I'm mistaken, that's what I was doing when I was passing the int value of the layoutID to generateUI(), which would use it in a setContentView of it's own, but that also resulted in a blank interface.

Comment: Which Activity class did you define in your Manifest? I'd expect that since BaseUIActivity  is abstract, you wouldn't have it in your manifest. You should add MainActivity  instead, please confirm.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla The activity is indeed MainActivity.

Comment: In that case, you need to move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in to the `MainActivity` instead of the abstract class. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla It fixes it sure, it was how I originally had it, however the whole point is I'm trying to take that out of the individual classes and have it called from the baseUI, but that results in the blank activity.

Comment: Yep, check my answer - I am also suggesting an example you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in to the `MainActivity` instead of the abstract class (`BaseUIActivity` ) because this will not be instantiated (which the is point of making it abstract). If you want to put some of the code in the base class so you can keep the actual code in the Activity classes smaller, then you can do that, but the `setContentView` should be in the `onCreate` of the Activity class which will be instantiated - in your case the `MainActivity`. Follow [the tutorial here](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/android-base-activity-class-example/), it provides a fairly good example of what you are trying to do.